# I accidentally sent a BPT token to a token contract. Can I get it back?

Tags: tokens, etherscan

Instead of transferring my BPT token to my wallet, I accidentally sent it to the contract itself.

I sent 99,546.988023218400325838 BPT to the address 0x471eb7dcf6647abaf838a5aad94940ce6932198c

The link below takes you to the etherscan contract with my BPT sitting in the address.

https://etherscan.io/token/0x471eb7dcf6647abaf838a5aad94940ce6932198c?a=0x471eb7dcf6647abaf838a5aad94940ce6932198c

Would the contract creator be able to send it back to me?

Comment: Someone please help me this is my life time savings. I'm desperate for help.

Answer (score 1):

The following two functions caught my attention:

```
// Absorb any tokens that have been sent to this contract into the pool
    function gulp(address token)
        external
        _logs_
        _lock_
    {
        require(_records[token].bound, "ERR_NOT_BOUND");
        _records[token].balance = IERC20(token).balanceOf(address(this));
    }

function _pushUnderlying(address erc20, address to, uint amount)
        internal
    {
        bool xfer = IERC20(erc20).transfer(to, amount);
        require(xfer, "ERR_ERC20_FALSE");
    }
```

I'm not exactly sure what they do but in theory they could be used to assign the tokens *somewhere*. You can probably even call the `gulp` yourself for the token and it seems to move the token to the pool - although I'm not sure what that means. The `_pushUnderlying` is trickier as it's `internal` and it's being called from various places in the contract.

Anyway, not all hope is lost and you should probably ask the contract managers or someone who knows how it works.

Comment: I appreciate your help so much! I've very new to this and made a dumb mistake. How do i contact the contract manager?

Comment: After quite some digging I guess it's this: https://balancer.finance/ . Sorry, don't have any exact details to give you but you can hopefully find some way to contact someone through there - maybe you can even ask in their community

Comment: Thank you so much I appreciate it greatly!